# Online IDE for XML-based formats

Tags: text-editor, cloud-service, xml

I want to let our users edit some proprietary scripts, which are essentially XML files, online. We can supply an XSD which can be used to provide validation, intelligent code completion and syntax highlighters.

Are there any available online services that provide this kind of capability to businesses?

Comment: Does [Google Docs Viewer](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/import-xml-file-google-docs-28667.html) help?

Comment: I am willing to learn, but I don't see any support for XSD there. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the XSD. I'd recommend these 3 addons for Google Drive / Dropbox :: [XML Editey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xml-editey/liglgghpccflcebckjdmiplgjbicachl/details), [_source_](http://www.floreysoft.com/en/products.html), [Codeanywhere](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/codeanywhere/ndcfkjjcjfpmmhdedhnbkknbehiadgjg/details), [_source_](https://codeanywhere.net/features), and [Xmlfuzz](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xmlfuzz/enomlpephhkihnlbdgjdnmgdkodhccgk/details), [_source_](https://suite.websecurify.com/market/xmlfuzz)

Comment: Hmm... Are you sure even one of them supports intelligent code completion and XSD?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just searched Google. I don't know much about XSD, only found that it is sort of a schema for xml files. As for the google drive suggestions, from the chrome store:  XML Editey :: **Live syntax checker** & Xmlfuzz :: **custom namespaces, elements and deeply nested structure** ... I guess you should ask this question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks, mk117. I asked and got downvoted and called an offtopic poster.

I suppose I'll have to write my own, which is just silly. You'd think there will be a universal component.

Comment: Well, I [::just found::](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_editors.asp) an application called [::XML Spy::](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html), and you can [::connect it to cloud services::](http://blog.altova.com/2011/01/xml-in-cloud.html), and the creators of the app, have also created a site called [:: Meta Team ::](http://www.altova.com/MetaTeamLaunch_041512.html). I don't know much about this app, but I'm sure there'll be a way you could allow users to edit the xml files as a team.... sorry that you got downvotes... I didn't know where else you could have posted your question.

Comment: There!!! That's the ticket. Thanks a lot. The funny thing is, I know Altova, but I did not realise they had a cloud service. I don't see a way to upvote a comment, but if you publish it in an answer, I will upvote it as much as I can. Thanks again.

Comment: Wait, hang on, that was premature :) . I think it's the other way around, a local tool connecting to a remote dataset.

Comment: Found another app: [Xopus](https://xopus.com/xopus-web-based-wysiwyg-xml-editor.html) ... does this help? .... Or maybe a  [:: stackoverflow question ::](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546106/web-based-xml-editor) ?

Comment: Yep, I think so, thanks!

Found some more resources:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495568/is-there-a-good-open-source-xsd-based-web-editor